# Angular 2 ngForm; Why all buttons call ngSubmit?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using `ngForm` and `ngSubmit`, and a bit confused why `save()` is getting called when I click buttons that have no action associated with them. Like the Cancel button here. It shouldn't do anything, right? Here's my form.

```
<form #editForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="save()">

    <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{'has-error': url.invalid}">
        <label for="url">Feed URL</label>
        <input type="url" class="form-control"
           id="url" name="url"
           [(ngModel)]="configuration.service" #url="ngModel"
           required pattern="https?://.+">
        <div class="has-error text-danger" [hidden]="url.valid">
            <span [hidden]="!url.errors?.required">
        URL is required
      </span>
      <span [hidden]="!url.errors?.pattern">
        URL is invalid
      </span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="editForm.form.invalid">
    Save
  </button>
  <button class="btn btn-warning">
    Cancel
  </button>

</form>
```

Any ideas why cancel is calling the `save` function?

Comment: Good info. Thank you.

Comment: Additionally you can read the spec on `button` here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button where it tells you that submit is the default type.

Comment: Ahhh! Thanks makes more sense.

Comment: Add  type='button' in button to fix this problem